# Store data to variable before saving to database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

How to save data before saving to database in C# windows application.
Like user enter some data to text fields. Until he press save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mentioned button event handler just use the standard way of declaring and assigning a variable(assuming your text box is named `textBox1`):

```
var data = textBox1.Text;
```